# What is this flowering plant and how can I encourage it to replace my lawn?

Tags: identification, flowers

Without getting on a soapbox about America's number one cultivated crop, I will just say that as a new homeowner I would like to get rid of as much lawn as possible from my front and back yards. I found this really pretty flower growing in the side lawn area and it appears to be some kind of ground cover, though I don't know if the previous owner planted it or it is native. What is it and how can I encourage it to replace my current grass?

[image: (Image: flowering ground cover with little purple flowers)]

Bigger image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9l4g8vk8a9fkcr/2020-05-02%2009.30.48.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's Creeping Charlie, an extremely invasive groundcover that is considered a noxious weed in many states. It's actually not very good at preventing weed growth (the primary reason for a groundcover, IMO) because its growth is too open and fails to keep weed seeds from hitting the ground; it also doesn't prevent sunlight from hitting the ground.

Encouraging this to grow is a **very bad idea**. If you live in an urban area, your neighbors will **not** be thrilled with you because this stuff spreads like crazy.

There are many other options for groundcovers that are much less nasty:

- Creeping Thyme (there are many cultivars)
- Mazus reptans (for shade and part-shade)
- Creeping veronica (many cultivars)
- White clover. This is also considered a weed by many people, although it's an excellent pollinator plant when in bloom and enriches the soil
- Some sedges (Carex species). If you don't want it to be necessarily walkable, I recommend a sedge called Carex pensylvanica - it spreads fairly quickly and has a grass-like look.

There are many other options for you. In all cases, groundcovers (including lawn grass) will enter any flower or vegetable beds, so edging or maintenance is a must.

If you want something low and moderately walkable, I suggest woolly thyme.

Comment: Aww, that's disappointing. Thank you!

Comment: I had to end my answer a little early due to an appointment. If you need a groundcover that you can walk on repeatedly (like you would on a lawn), search for "walkables" and "groundcover". You should get some interesting choices.

Comment: thank you, I probably won't get to doing my front lawn for a while unless it's something easy like something already prone to growing there, I'll probably just rip out the Charlie and leave it be while I do the back lawn first. Both parts of the front lawn adjoin to my neighbors lawns so it'll be tricky.